# Using comma with an update sentence

Tags: sql, sql-update

I want to update a row which has some html tags inside. For instance:

```
 src='/imagem.png'></ p></ body>

> UPDATE ISTANBUL_TABLE  SET TEXT = '<
> body>< p>< img src='/imagem.png '></
> p></ body>'  WHERE  1=1
```

You see after `src='` means the query ends, but it does not end. How can i solve it without using `"` (double comma)?  Any solution please?

best regards bk

Comment: Why would you want to avoid using double ' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the single-quotes, by typing them twice:

```
UPDATE ISTANBUL_TABLE SET TEXT = '<  body>< p>< img src=''/imagem.png ''>' WHERE 1=1
```

Also, your `WHERE` clause is nonsensical and can be dropped entirely

```
UPDATE ISTANBUL_TABLE SET TEXT = '<body><p><img src=''/imagem.png''>'
```

Comment: double single-quotes is ok then?
I mean where clause  still has meaning after using twice single-quotes.

Comment: Not crazy about typing extra quotes -- it would be hard to spot an error. But I totally agree that the WHERE clause is not needed.

Comment: yeah you are right. but i will need the where clause for different cases of next operations

Comment: Yes, doubling single quotes is just escaping them so that they don't close the string. One of the (number of) reasons why it's neater to use parameterised SQL instead of adhoc generated like this as you don't need to worry about escaping like this

Answer (score 1):

Use parameterised SQL:

```
UPDATE ISTANBUL_TABLE SET TEXT = @HTML WHERE...
```

Then from your calling code, you just pass in the @HTML parameter and don't need to double up the single quotes.